Not able to autenticate when adding a VisualSVN repo to FishEye
I'm getting the following error when trying to add a SVN repository to FishEye.
Our SVN is hosted with VisualSVN on a Windows Server running as a Windows service with a dedicated service account. Our FishEye is also hosted on a Windows Server running as a Windows service with the same the same service account.
FishEye configurations used to add the repo:
SVN URL: https://example.com/svn/myrepo
Path: blank
Username: domain\same-service-account-above
Password: mypassword
Unable to get info for the repository root for myrepo
svn: E170001: Negotiate authentication failed: 'No valid credentials provided'
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:68)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication$1.run(DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.java:175)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication$1.run(DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.java:166)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.authenticate(DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.java:221)

Unable to get Repository Root URL for myrepo:https://example.com/svn/myrepo/

Exception getting Fisheye access control
svn: E170001: Negotiate authentication failed: 'No valid credentials provided'
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:68)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication$1.run(DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.java:175)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication$1.run(DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.java:166)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.authenticate(DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.java:221)

Connection test failed.
svn: E170001: Negotiate authentication failed: 'No valid credentials provided'
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:68)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:57)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication$1.run(DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.java:175)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication$1.run(DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.java:166)
at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.authenticate(DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.java:221)

Error testing connection.
Unable to connect to repository. Please check the settings.
at com.atlassian.fisheye.spi.admin.impl.DefaultRepositoryAdminService.testConnectionFor(DefaultRepositoryAdminService.java:973)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Connection failed.


It seems that your Fisheye installation is using SVNKit library to enable SVN support. Replace it with JavaHL (Native SVN support) as described at https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/native-support-for-svn-960155253.html and try again. So far it looks like support for Integrated Windows Authentication (IWA) and Negotiate authentication (Kerberos or NTLM) is disabled in your Fisheye installation since SVNKit doesn't support it. Switching to JavaHL usually helps.
